# Angular2 how do they save to cache?

Tags: javascript, angular, caching

I was trying out the 5 min Anuglar2 Tutorial and when it said that you are able to use external templates I tried it.

My component looks like this

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
  url: "component.html"
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Alice';
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

I had a mistake in my external template and fixed it, but the HTML file was still cached so I couldn't the effects in the browser.

Figuring out how they cache it I looked at the code on [Github](https://github.com/angular)

I found this

```
#angular/modules/angular2/src/core/compiler/template_loader.js

@Injectable()
export class TemplateLoader {
  _xhr: XHR;
  _htmlCache: StringMap;
  _baseUrls: Map<Type, string>;
  _urlCache: Map<Type, string>;
  _urlResolver: UrlResolver;

  constructor(xhr: XHR, urlResolver: UrlResolver) {
    this._xhr = xhr;
    this._urlResolver = urlResolver;
    this._htmlCache = StringMapWrapper.create();
    this._baseUrls = MapWrapper.create();
    this._urlCache = MapWrapper.create();
  }

  // TODO(vicb): union type: return an Element or a Promise<Element>
  load(template: Template) {
    if (isPresent(template.inline)) {
      return DOM.createTemplate(template.inline);
    }

    if (isPresent(template.url)) {
      var url = this.getTemplateUrl(template);
      var promise = StringMapWrapper.get(this._htmlCache, url);

      if (isBlank(promise)) {
        promise = this._xhr.get(url).then(function (html) {
          var template = DOM.createTemplate(html);
          return template;
        });
        StringMapWrapper.set(this._htmlCache, url, promise);
      }

      return promise;
    }
```

So I check out the StringMapWrapper  **angular/modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.es6**

and for set the code is just

```
static set(map, key, value) {
    map[key] = value;
  }
```

I saw that the StringMapWrapper comes from global

```
export var StringMap = global.Object;
```

But looking in **angular/modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.es6**  I cant figure out where the Map is cached.

I do not know much about the caching process and hope someone could explain how they do it in this case.

Comment: When you tell the browser to clear the cache and reload, does it work? Also, what HTTP server are you using and what are the headers in your HTTP response?

Comment: Yeah, works when I clear the cache. I would just like to know how it gets to the cache in the first place. I dont seem to find the place where it happens in the code.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, go to dev tools and set the "disable cache while dev tools is open" setting, does that cause the cache to be disabled?

Comment: Yes, then everything will update the way it should. So are the Browsers automatically caching?

Comment: The caching is being driven by the cache headers of your HTTP server

Comment: @unobf : thanks for this very useful tip. This option is also present in Firefox developer tools :-)

Comment: @unof  it's not about http cache, it's about cache for single visit, like revisiting the same page while surfing an Ajax based site like Angular based websites. The http cache may prevail even after closing the tab and revisiting the web site, but solution above shown in Question is a memory based solution, for more see this article http://www.ravinderpayal.com/blogs/12Jan2017-Ajax-Cache-Mangement-Angular2-Service.html

Answer (score 0):

`StringMapWrapper.create()` creates an object literal `{}`. They use something like `StringMapWrapper` for Dart support where these primitives are created differently in the other language. In short all they're doing is this

```
var cache = {};
xhr(templateUrl).then(template => {
  cache[templateUrl] = template;
  return template;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@gdi2290 had nearly answered your question, and if you want to understand more about Cache Management in JavaScript/TypeScript, please see my post here http://www.ravinderpayal.com/blogs/12Jan2017-Ajax-Cache-Mangement-Angular2-Service.html .

There is a step by step explanation of a cache management class which acts as  Layer to  AJAX, and can be injected to components as Service. Here's a synopsis of code from class:-

```
 private loadPostCache(link:string){
     if(!this.loading[link]){
               this.loading[link]=true;
               this.links[link].forEach(a=>this.dataObserver[a].next(false));
               this.http.get(link)
                   .map(this.setValue)
                   .catch(this.handleError).subscribe(
                   values => {
                       this.data[link] = values;
                       delete this.loading[link];
                       this.links[link].forEach(a=>this.dataObserver[a].next(false));
                   },
                   error => {
                       delete this.loading[link];
                   }
               );
           }
    }

    private setValue(res: Response) {
        return res.json() || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    postCache(link:string): Observable<Object>{

         return Observable.create(observer=> {
             if(this.data.hasOwnProperty(link)){
                 observer.next(this.data[link]);
             }
             else{
                 let _observable=Observable.create(_observer=>{
                     this.counter=this.counter+1;
                     this.dataObserver[this.counter]=_observer;
                     this.links.hasOwnProperty(link)?this.links[link].push(this.counter):(this.links[link]=[this.counter]);
                     _observer.next(false);
                 });
                 this.loadPostCache(link);
                 _observable.subscribe(status=>{
                     if(status){
                         observer.next(this.data[link]);
                     }
                     }
                 );
             }
            });
        }
```