# Meteor-Angular2 HTML Templates not updating on code change

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular

I'm currently working on [a project](https://github.com/ShMcK/Angular2-Meteor-Demos) running Meteor 1.1.0.2 using the following packages:

```
meteor-platform
angular:angular2
netanelgilad:angular2-typescript
```

I've run into a frustrating issue. When I create a template:

/someTemplate.ng.html

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<!-- displays: Hello World -->
```

It will run. But on subsequent changes to that template, it won't update.

/someTemplate.ng.html

```
<h1>Hello Somebody</h1>
<!-- displays: Hello World -->
```

This wasn't always the case, but I'm unsure if or what change may have caused the issue.

It seems the templates are being cached and thus don't update. As you can imagine, this makes for a frustrating dev experience.

Same named templates are even cached across different apps.

If I start a new project, pointing to the same template name, it fetches the old template.

/someTemplate.ng.html

```
<h1>New Meteor Project</h1>
<!-- displays: Hello World -->
```

Any ideas whether the issue is package specific or Meteor related. Has anyone else experienced the same problem? Any quick/hard fixes?

Comment: by serving the pages with a server with caching disabled that would also work, for example using http-server with option -c-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CTRL + F5

In Chrome ["Disable cache"](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings) (ONLY for pages which have DevTools open)

[Angular2 how do they save to cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433978/angular2-how-do-they-save-to-cache)

Comment: Disabling cache in Chrome DevTools did the trick. Thank you so much!